# How to change BottomNavigationBarItem icon when selected, Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, bottombar

I am new to Flutter. I have a `BottomNavigationBar` with 4 items. I want to change icon of the item when pressed. Please help.

This is what I have done so far.

```
bottomNavigationBar : new BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            this.index = index;
          }
          );
          _navigateToScreens(index);
        },
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              icon: new Image.asset('images/1.0x/icon1.png'),
              title: new Text("Route1", style: new TextStyle(
                  color: const Color(0xFF06244e), fontSize: 14.0))),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Image.asset('images/1.0x/icon2.png'),
              title: new Text("Route2", style: new TextStyle(
                  color: const Color(0xFF06244e), fontSize: 14.0))),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Image.asset('images/1.0x/icon3.png'),
              title: new Text("Route3", style: new TextStyle(
                  color: const Color(0xFF06244e), fontSize: 14.0),)),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Image.asset('images/1.0x/icon4.png'),
              title: new Text("Route4", style: new TextStyle(
                  color: const Color(0xFF06244e), fontSize: 14.0),))
        ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have posted it as an answer. please check.

Comment: instead of posting as answer, you can edit the question.

Comment: Yes. my mistake. I will do as such. Thank you

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can change the icon by checking for the current index is equal to the index of `BottomNavigationBarItem` index.

Simple example with static index values:

```
bottomNavigationBar : new BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            this.index = index;
          }
          );
          _navigateToScreens(index);
        },
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              icon: index==0?new Image.asset('images/1.0x/icon1.png'):new Image.asset('images/1.0x/newIcon.png'),
              title: new Text("Route1", style: new TextStyle(
                  color: const Color(0xFF06244e), fontSize: 14.0))),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: index==1?new Image.asset('images/1.0x/icon2.png'):new Image.asset('images/1.0x/newIcon.png'),
              title: new Text("Route2", style: new TextStyle(
                  color: const Color(0xFF06244e), fontSize: 14.0))),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: index==2?new Image.asset('images/1.0x/icon3.png'):new Image.asset('images/1.0x/newIcon.png'),
              title: new Text("Route3", style: new TextStyle(
                  color: const Color(0xFF06244e), fontSize: 14.0),)),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: index==3?new Image.asset('images/1.0x/icon4.png'):new Image.asset('images/1.0x/newIcon.png'),
              title: new Text("Route4", style: new TextStyle(
                  color: const Color(0xFF06244e), fontSize: 14.0),))
        ])
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Bad idea. That's too tedious to write. Instead you can wrap your list in a `Theme`. And override a few properties. Such as `primaryColor`, `accentColor`, and `caption.color`. These values are the values that BottomNavigationBar uses to icons depending on if they are selected or not.

Comment: I do agree up on your view.But how would that change the Icon, which is an `Image.asset` here?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I thought it was about changing the selected icon color. Ignore my message then.

Comment: @Darky, Yes, I need to change the icon, else your answer would have been correct. Thank you

Comment: I also need to set the first image in first BottomNavigationBarItem and second image (in the conditional expression) in rest of the items when pressing back button after moving to other screens. How is this possible? please help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Be more clear or point any visual reference

Comment: What is _navigateToScreens here?

Answer (score 55):

There is new feature added in flutter in  BottomNavigationBarItem that is `active icon`. we can use it to tell what should be the icon when a tab is active

```
bottomNavigationBar : new BottomNavigationBar(
    currentIndex: index,
    onTap: (int index) {
      setState(() {
        this.index = index;
      }
      );
      _navigateToScreens(index);
    },
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    items: [
      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          icon: new Image.asset('images/1.0x/icon1.png'),
          activeIcon:new Image.asset('images/1.0x/newIcon.png'),
          title: new Text("Route1", style: new TextStyle(
              color: const Color(0xFF06244e), fontSize: 14.0))),
      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Image.asset('images/1.0x/icon2.png'),
          activeIcon:new Image.asset('images/1.0x/newIcon.png'),
          title: new Text("Route2", style: new TextStyle(
              color: const Color(0xFF06244e), fontSize: 14.0))),
      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Image.asset('images/1.0x/icon3.png'),
          activeIcon: new Image.asset('images/1.0x/newIcon.png'),
          title: new Text("Route3", style: new TextStyle(
              color: const Color(0xFF06244e), fontSize: 14.0),)),
      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Image.asset('images/1.0x/icon4.png'),
          activeIcon: new Image.asset('images/1.0x/newIcon.png'),
          title: new Text("Route4", style: new TextStyle(
              color: const Color(0xFF06244e), fontSize: 14.0),))
    ]),
```

Hope someone will find this useful.

Comment: title was Deprecated, use Label instead

Answer (score 13):

If anyone is looking for a solution to change the Bottom Navigation Bar Item's color,when "type" is set to "shifting", then give this a try:

```
type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
  items: [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      activeIcon: Icon(
          Icons.home,
          color: Colors.grey[700],
        ),
      icon: Icon(
          Icons.home,
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
      title: Text(
        'Home',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey[600]
          ),
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 10):

If all you want to change is the **color** of the BottomNavigationBarItem icon, you don't need to have two images with different colors for one icon. Just one is enough.

You can use ImageIcon to create icon from custom image, and use it's color property to change the icon color, using the value of the currentIndex, like this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    currentIndex: currentTab,
    onTap: (int index) {
      setState(() {
        currentTab = index;
        currentPage = pages[index];
      });
    },
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: ImageIcon(
            AssetImage("assets/img/tab1.png"),
            color: currentTab == 0
                ? Colors.orange
                : Colors.black,
          ),
          title: Text('Title 1',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 10.0,
                color: currentTab == 0
                    ? Colors.orange
                    : Colors.black),
          )
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: ImageIcon(
            AssetImage("assets/img/tab2.png"),
            color: currentTab == 1
                ? Colors.orange
                : Colors.black,
          ),
          title: Text('Title 2',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 10.0,
                color: currentTab == 1
                    ? Colors.orange
                    : Colors.black),)
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: ImageIcon(
            AssetImage("assets/img/tab3.png"),
            color: currentTab == 2
                ? Colors.orange
                : Colors.black,
          ),
          title: Text('Title 3',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 10.0,
                color: currentTab == 2
                    ? Colors.orange
                    : Colors.black),)
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: ImageIcon(
            AssetImage("assets/img/tab4.png"),
            color: currentTab == 3
                ? Colors.orange
                : Colors.black,
          ),
          title: Text('Title 4',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 10.0,
                color: currentTab == 3
                    ? Colors.orange
                    : Colors.black),)
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Hope someone will find this useful.

Comment: If you are wanting to change the selected icon's color you just set the "fixedColor" on the BottomNavigationBar itself.e.g. BottomNavigationBar(
              fixedColor: colorPrimary,
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text("first")),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.pie_chart), title: Text("insights"))
                ],
             ),
          )

Comment: This should be the selected answer alongside @miloss solution. Really neat and simple without having to switch the images every time the tab is clicked

Answer (score 10):

**2020**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Heqn2.jpg)

2 way

The better way currently to do it is :

```
    selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
    unselectedItemColor: Color(0xFFF434A50),
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/tab1.png"),),
            title: Text('Agents'),
        ),
    ]
```

Alternative way :

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
   activeIcon: Image.asset("assets/tab1.png",width: 15,color: Colors.white,),
   icon: Image.asset("assets/tab1.png",width: 15,color: Color(0xFFF434A50),),
   title: Text('Agents'),
 ),
```

> activeIcon - Selected tab
>
> icon - Deselected tab

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to change the color and not the icon itself, `fixedColor` determines the colour of the icon when it's selected:

```
BottomNavigationBar(
        ...
        fixedColor: Colors.red,
        ...
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Changed Active Icon for Bottom Navigation Bar in this way if you are showing icon from Image Assets:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
              activeIcon: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/useractive.png',
                height: 25,
                width: 25,
              ),
              icon: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/user.png',
                height: 25,
                width: 25,
              ),
              title: Text('My Time Out')
),
```

Comment: late 2022 and material 3 update. there is no title argument available. So change it with (label:String)

BottomNavigationBarItem(
              activeIcon: Image.asset(
                'lib/assets/images/homeActive.png',
                height: 25,
                width: 25,
              ),
              icon: Image.asset(
                'lib/assets/images/homePassive.png',
                height: 25,
                width: 25,
              ),
              label: 'Home'
          )

Answer (score 1):

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
          activeIcon: Image.asset(
            'lib/assets/images/homeActive.png',
            height: 25,
            width: 25,
          ),
          icon: Image.asset(
            'lib/assets/images/homePassive.png',
            height: 25,
            width: 25,
          ),
          label: 'Home'
      )
```

**update 2022**

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way. At the **BottomNavigationBar**, there are two attributes **selectedItemColor** and **unselectedItemColor**

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    ...
    selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    unselectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
    ...
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.search),
        title: Text('Search'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.star),
        title: Text('Featured'),
      ),
   ],
  ),
```

Comment: This seems to affect text label colour only. The icon colour is unaffected. Unfortunately, I've also tried `(un)selectedIconTheme` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

```
color: _selectedIndex == ThisIndex?SelectedColor:normalColor,
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanna add to the existing answers: Although `fixedColor`, `(un)selectedItemColor` are the ways to go, there is a gotcha:

They will be overriden by `BottomNavigationBarItem.icon.color`!

So make sure you get rid of the hardcoded icon color first.