# Flutter - How can i change the background color of an active BottomNavBar item?

Tags: flutter, dart, background, navbar, square

I have searched pretty long but sadly can not find a related answer. How can I change the background color of my active route-item? See on the picture or the current Audible or Clock App on the iPhone. I'm using CupertinoTabBar but can´t find any solution to this problem. I just want a rounded Square behind my active item.

[Audible App - Bottom Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBfjP.jpg)

followed my current Navbar Code

```
CupertinoTabScaffold(
          tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
            iconSize: 30,
            activeColor: SymeColorPurple,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            inactiveColor: Colors.black12,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.settings
                  ),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  "Inventory",
                  style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Padding(
                  child: Icon(Icons.home),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  "Home",
                  style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Padding(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.camera_alt
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  "Camera",
                  style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          tabBuilder: (context, index) {
            switch (index) {
              case 0:
                return InventoryPage();
                break;
              case 1:
                return HomeView();
                break;
              case 2:
                return CameraPage();
                break;
              default:
                return HomeView();
                break;
            }
          }),
```

Comment: Sorry to say this but yah Cupertino will not have that kind of functionality in first place just think about it ios cupertino designs are backgrounds needs to be same while icon and text color will be different

also there's no property in the class 

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabBar-class.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BottomNavigationBarItem-class.html

So no you can't be able to specify property but you can be able to use stack and have work arounds.

Comment: oh ok didn't know that.. so what should I use instead?

Comment: You can create you own custom bottom bar to achieve that. With a Row space even you can easily pass your items having equal amount of width, when selected, change the state and keep a background color.

Comment: Maybe this will help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029966/how-to-change-bottomnavigationbaritem-icon-when-selected-flutter